# conflict between implode function and strtotime

Tags: php

I have a problem in this code:

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

function dateImplodeFunction($year, $month, $day){
  $array = array($year, $month, $day);
  $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( implode("-", $array)));
  return $date;
}
```

based on the code above I'm going to create a function where there are 3 inputs month, day and a year. When I input those 3 these variables will passed to this function, combine those 3 variables and use the implode function to create a format based on what date you specified. for instance let's say if I input 10/01/1989 it will echo the display 10/01/1989.

also I need to use date function together with strtotime function (refer to the code above) for database, setting my date field into date data type.

The problem here is if I input 10-01-1989, it returns/dipslays the value of 01-01-1970 why??
I figured it out that there is a conflict between strtotime and implode function due to test. I've search through google but it find none. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

sorry for the bad english =P

Comment: Shouldn't `implode("-", $array)` be `implode("", $array)?` Where did `-` come from?

Comment: If you want to get `Y-m-d` format you should "glue" the array with `-` don't you?

Comment: @core1024 Right, I had it confused with explode, get confused sometimes implode and explode syntax

Comment: i think it should be order problem make sure that order of the post data is correct or make sure its post has values, 1970-01-01 becomes when the time is set to 0.

Comment: @core1024 yes "-" is used to glue the array. there are many ways to glue the array other than "-" you can use other special chars like "/" or "?" but I use the "-" for mysql format.

Comment: @user1179459 I dont think my order of post data is incorect since I following the date format in php.net

Comment: @Martin what kind of input is `10-01-1989` year 1989, month 01, day 10 or year 10, month 01 and day 1989? And one more quastion - why instead of `implode` you don't just use `$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day` or even `"$year-$month-$day"`?

Comment: @core1024 the format input that I'm using is 10-01-1989 or Y-m-d date format where year = 1989, month = 10 and day = 01. I never though of that hehe gee thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mktime` :

```
function dateImplodeFunction($year, $month, $day)
{
    return date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
}
```

[Documentation of mktime here](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the [`Date Time class`](https://www.php.net/datetime).

```
$month = '07';
$day = '26';
$year = '2012';

$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$date = new DateTime( "{$year}-{$month}-{$day}", $timezone );
print $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

# Output: 2012-07-26 00:00:00
```

http://codepad.org/VxwDHPeU